# how to get this year opening from last year closing with condition?

Tags: t-sql

I have table of data as below needs to use t-sql to generate

```
Year | Id    | Entitle | Use | Max
-----------------------------------
2016 | 0001  | 15      | 5   | 20
2017 | 0001  | 15      | 2   | 20
2018 | 0001  | 15      | 4   | 20
```

I need to get opening and closing for each year, this year opening will be last year (opening + Entitle - Use), but it cannot exceed Max, if exceed Max then "Max" will be the opening.

this is the result I expected

```
year | Id   | Opening | Entitle | Use | Max | Closing
-----------------------------------------------------
2016 | 0001 | 0       | 15      | 5   | 20  | 10
2017 | 0001 | 10      | 15      | 2   | 20  | 23
2018 | 0001 | 20      | 15      | 4   | 20  | 31
```

Comment: Could you please post some code examples of what you have tried to get the expected result?

Comment: Please edit your question. How do you calculate your `closing` ? How do you calculate the `opening` for 2016 since you do not have information about the previous year?

Comment: the problem is, opening is take from last year closing but cannot exceed the Max, and this year closing will also take in this year opening.

Comment: I try to use this left outer join SELECT TY.* 
FROM Data TY 
LEFT Outer Join Data LY ON TY.ID=LY.ID AND TY.year-1=LY.year but I cannot figure out how to get first opening to calculate the closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option, a recursive CTE will get you there.

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [Year] INT
      , [Id] NVARCHAR(10)
      , [Entitle] INT
      , [Use] INT
      , [Max] INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [Year]
                        , [Id]
                        , [Entitle]
                        , [Use]
                        , [Max]
                      )
VALUES ( 2016, '0001', 15, 5, 20 )
     , ( 2017, '0001', 15, 2, 20 )
     , ( 2018, '0001', 15, 4, 20 );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [Year]
                        , [Id]
                        , [Entitle]
                        , [Use]
                        , [Max]
                      )
VALUES ( 2015, '0002', 20, 7, 20 )
     , ( 2016, '0002', 20, 7, 20 )
     , ( 2017, '0002', 20, 4, 20 )
     , ( 2018, '0002', 20, 13, 20 );


WITH [cte]
AS ( SELECT      [a].[Year]
               , [a].[Id]
               , 0 AS [Opening]
               , [a].[Entitle]
               , [a].[Use]
               , [a].[Entitle] - [a].[Use] AS [Closing]
     FROM        @TestData [a]
     --Cross apply here to get our first record, earliest year for each Id for our anchor
     CROSS APPLY (
                     SELECT   [aa].[Id]
                            , MIN([aa].[Year]) AS [Year]
                     FROM     @TestData [aa]
                     WHERE    [aa].[Id] = [a].[Id]
                     GROUP BY [aa].[Id]
                 ) [aaa]
     WHERE       [a].[Year] = [aaa].[Year]
                 AND [a].[Id] = [aaa].[Id]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT     [c].[Year]
              , [c].[Id]
              , CASE WHEN [b].[Closing] > [c].[Max] THEN [c].[Max]
                     ELSE [b].[Closing]
                END
              , [c].[Entitle]
              , [c].[Use]
              , CASE WHEN [b].[Closing] > [c].[Max] THEN [c].[Max]
                     ELSE [b].[Closing]
                END + [c].[Entitle] - [c].[Use] AS [Closing]
     FROM       [cte] [b]
     INNER JOIN @TestData [c]
         ON [c].[Id] = [b].[Id]
            AND [c].[Year] = [b].[Year] + 1 )
SELECT   *
FROM     [cte]
ORDER BY [cte].[Id]
       , [cte].[Year];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple SQL will not be enough here. You need to go trough each row and calculate the closing and opening values based on the previous year.

The idea would be to loop trough each row. Store the results. Add the results into a temp table.

I have made you the code here. Please note that I have used SSMS to implement it.

```
 DECLARE @TempTable table (_ID varchar(255),Year int,Opening int, Entitle int,Used int,Max int, Closing int)

DECLARE @idColumn INT
DECLARE @ID varchar(255)
DECLARE @entitle INT 
DECLARE @used INT
DECLARE @max INT
DECLARE @opening INT
DECLARE @closing INT
DECLARE @year INT
SELECT @idColumn = min( Id ) FROM MyTable

WHILE @idColumn is not null
BEGIN

SET @year =  (SELECT Year FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn)
SET @ID =  (SELECT [_ID] FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn)
IF @idColumn = 1
 BEGIN
    SET @entitle =  (SELECT Entitle FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn);
    SET @used =  (SELECT Used FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn);
    SET @opening = 0;
    SET @closing = @opening + @entitle - @used;
    SET @max =  (SELECT Max FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn);
 END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @opening = @opening + @entitle - @used;
    IF @opening > @max
     BEGIN
       SET @opening = @max;
     END
    SET @entitle =  (SELECT Entitle FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn);
    SET @used =  (SELECT Used FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn);
    SET @max =  (SELECT Max FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @idColumn);
    SET @closing = @opening + @entitle - @used;
  END

INSERT INTO @TempTable (_ID , Year , Opening , Entitle , Used ,Max , Closing )
VALUES (@ID, @year, @opening, @entitle, @used, @max, @closing);
SELECT @idColumn = min( Id ) FROM MyTable WHERE Id > @idColumn
END

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

[image]

Comment: If the OP's data has the value `0001` in column `Id` for every row how does this work? Tip: `select @entitle = Entitle, @used = Used, ... from MyTable where Id = @idColumn;`.

Comment: The id column I have used is the identity for MyTable. I have made some changes and now you have the _ID column as requested, (all of the same values)

Comment: thanks Alex Leo for providing a solution for my question, but I think solution from Tim is better and easier to integrate into my project.

Comment: @AlexChea Hey, no problem, at least you had more than one solution to choose from :-)